# can graylog2 output to flat file and elasticsearch at the same time?

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2

I'm very new to graylog2. I finally have it up and running, storing logs to elasticsearch. My question is: can graylog2 also dump to flat file? if so can it dump log files to both flat file and elastic search simultaneously?  I can't seem to find the answer googling. If any log guru knows the answer, would u kindly point me to a right direction?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can send syslog messages to standard rsyslog port udp/514 and then from rsyslog to graylog2.

### Rsyslog.conf

> if $fromhost-ip == '10.10.205.1' then /var/log/hosts/host1.log
>
> if $fromhost-ip == '10.10.205.1' then @0.0.0.0:515